# Big O Complexity algorithm

Tags: javascript, performance, big-o

I'm just learning about Big O notation, and I've been going through a few thought puzzles, and I just thought I'd verify with people whether I'm thinking through things correctly.

In Javascript would this be considered an O(n) time solution for a search for common items through two arrays? Or does the language perform lookups within an object and iterate through n elements within the object the same way it iterates through an array?

```
function findCommon (input, input2){
  var key = {};
  var out = [];
  for(var i=0; i<input.length; i++){
    key[input[i]] = true;
  }
  for(var j=0; j<input2.length; j++){
    if(key[input2[j]] == true){
      out.push(input2[j]);
    }
  }
  return out;
}
```

findCommon([1, 2, 4, 6, 7], [3, 4, 5, 7])
-->[4, 7]

Comment: It´s O(n) . And, about the JS thing: It´s not the problem of your code, is it? (In reality, i´m sure they use better data structures than plain linear array)

Comment: You almost answered my question RE js data structures. Is it safe to say that an object is the best data structure for performing lookups in a set of data? Or is this language dependent?

Comment: Yes, it depends on language (as there are many languages without objects) and your JS engine and...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let `m` be the length of `input` and `n` be the length of `input2`. The complexity of the first loop is `O(m)` and the complexity of the second one is `O(n)`. Whenever you are facing sequential code, complexities are summed up (they would've been multiplied if the loops were nested instead of sequential), giving us a total `O(m + n)` and that is the exact upper bound and is obviously linear in the size of the arguments.

Now, `m + n <= 2 * max(m, n)` so you may say that the function is also `O(2 * max(m, n))` but we can of course drop the constant so that gives us `O(max(m, n))`. Let us assume that `n` is always greater than `m` (it's not a big deal as it doesn't change much). That gives us `O(n)`, so indeed you can say that the algorithm is `O(n)` but a more precise notation would be `O(m + n)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your function consist of two `O(n)` complexities. Therefore, total complexity of your function is `O(n)`. As mentioned in comments, I would like to clarify that you have two different `O(n)` and `O(m)` which are not equal to `O(2n)` (however, you would still drop all constants). But it doesn't matter in your case, since complexity depends not on size of `m` or `n`, but on complexity of structure ( single `for loop` in your case)

Comment: I think that formally you would need an additional explanation that, you have 2 inputs of lenght n and m, and you assume that the longer one is always n. With that assumption you can approx `O(2n)` = `O(n)`